# Multi valued profile property mapping to AD in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, profile, multivalue

I'm trying to map my skills and responsibilities profile sections to one of the custom properties in Active Directory (extensionattribute1 , 2, etc). I'm entering comma seperated values in AD and it's importing the values fine but sees the comma seperated values as one value on import. i.e. 'C#,asp.net,javascript' rather than 'C#', 'asp.net', 'Javascript'.

Any ideas. I'm almost there it's just not spliting the values correctly on import.

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just put a CSV string into an AD property and have SharePoint treat this as a multi valued property.  This is because the AD property is still classified as a single valued property.  Some AD properties are actually/inherently multi-valued, which wouldn't require the use of any CSV construct to input the multiple values into AD.  I believe if the AD property is multi-valued, then SharePoint can import this into a SharePoint multi-valued property.  Otherwise you'll have to run some custom code in a timer job or something that would parse out the CSV components of the AD property and update the user's profile directly via the SharePoint object model.

[This page](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/articles/active_directory_programming_guide.aspx) explains the difference between single and multi valued AD properties:

Answer (score 0):

If you have these values in an external database, you can use those as a secondary data source using Business Data Catalog (BDC).

You could map your data as either 1:1 mapping or 1:many

Heres an example
http://www.toddbaginski.com/blog/archive/2009/03/08/45.aspx